# Apply rbindlist on a function that returns multiple tables

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

We are using the `inner <- rbindlist(lapply(..., FUN))` to combine the results of simulation results created using the `future` package. In this particular case `rbindlist(lapply(..., FUN))` is nested by `rbindlist(future_lapply(..., inner))`because the simulations are spread over threads.

This works fine as long as `FUN()` returns one table. We now want to do a more detailed analysis of the simulations which requires us to return more than one table from `FUN()`. The tables will now have different shapes and we want to combine like for like.

How to combine tables together using `*apply()` function if `FUN()` returns multiple tables? We came up with a solution that works below but doesn't compose as well. Any suggestions on how to improve this code to fit in the `*apply(X, FUN)` structure again?

```
foo <- list(
  list(data.table(a = 1), data.table(b = 2)), 
  list(data.table(a = 3), data.table(b = 4)),
  list(data.table(a = 5), data.table(b = 6))
)
MapRbind <- function(...) {
  Map(rbind, ...) 
}
do.call(MapRbind, foo)
```

I don't see a way to move the call to `do.call()` into `MapRbind()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it?

```
MapRbind <- function(our_list) {
  do.call(function(...) Map(rbind, ...), our_list)
}

> MapRbind(foo)
[[1]]
   a
1: 1
2: 3
3: 5

[[2]]
   b
1: 2
2: 4
3: 6
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed seems to work. I see I made an error when writing up this idea.

Comment: Pretty elegant solution you came up with-I just moved the pieces around. I would probably have done something simpler such as: `lapply(1:2, function(i) rbindlist(lapply(foo, "[[", i)))`

Comment: The number of tables might vary and the caller might not be aware of this (could be made aware but I’m lazy) so this general solution has my preference. It would be even better if someone knows of a way to do this without helpers and/or leveraging `rbindlist`

Comment: An idea I had was to write `lapply(data.table::transpose(lapply(...)), rbindlist)` but `transpose` doesn't work like that.

Comment: You *could*  do that with `purrr`: `lapply(purrr::transpose(foo), rbindlist)`